# Relativistic inelastic collsion

Tags: special-relativity, collision

I want to calculate the collision of two bodys each with knowen Four-momentum, that merge into 1 body after the collision.
I chose my coordiante System in a way, that p1 only has one component in one direction, lets say x bzw. 1-direction.
I want to calculate the mass of the outgoing particle m3. Therefor I square both sides of the Four-momentum conservation equation: $m_1 u_1 + m_2 u_2= m_3 u_3$. I can use, that the square of every Four-Velocity is $c^2$. Now I need to find the value of $u_1 u_2$. Since the scalar product is lorentz invariant, I do a transformation to the system of rest for particle 1. The idea is, that $u_1$ simplyfies to $({c, 0, 0, 0})^T$.

$u_2$ becomes:$(\frac{c^2 - v w_1}{
 c \sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2} \sqrt{1 - w^2/c^2}}, \frac {-v + w_1} {
 \sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2} {\sqrt{1 - w^2/c^2}}} , \frac {w_2} {\sqrt{
 1 - w^2/c^2}},\frac {w_3} {\sqrt{1 - w^2/c^2}})^T$

Then u1*u2 becomes: $(c^2 - v w_1)/(\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2} \sqrt{1 - w^2/c^2})$.
The rest is equation manipulation.
Are my thoughts correct?

Comment: We have MathJax running on the site. Mathemtics can be written in a $\LaTeX$-math-mode-alike language. Put the code between single $ sings for in-line or double dollar signs for block set. Example: `\sqrt{1 - (u/c)^2}` typeset's as $\sqrt{1 - (u/c)^2}$. Use `\frac{}{}` for upright fractions, `_` for subscripts.